# How to avoid multiple instances of DetailViewController in master/detail iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my master-detail app, created from the Xcode template, it appears that in MasterViewController's prepareForSegue, the destination view controller is never the same instance of my DetailViewController - I get a new instance every time:

```
    DetailViewController    *detailController = (DetailViewController *)[[segue destinationViewController] topViewController];
```

In addition, the segue.destinationViewController.topViewController is not the same as the detailViewController obtained when the masterViewController starts up. Within MasterViewController viewDidLoad:

```
    self.detailViewController = (DetailViewController *)[[self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject] topViewController];
```

This is a problem for me because my detailViewController installs observers for events from an AVPlayer object, and the observers have to be paired: addObserver/removeObserver. If one instance does not remove the observers, I get more than one instance that receives the notification(s).

Is there some way to ensure that I am always using a single/same instance of DetailViewController?

Comment: I think that's the expected behavior. `Storyboard` that is related with your `segue` will create a new `ViewController` each time. `segue.destinationviewcontroller` doesn't necessarily return the old one!!! After you pop your detailView if you are not holding any strong references to it, at some point that viewcontroller will be deallocated. So how about you remove your observes whenever you pop your `detailViewcontroller`. probably in `deinit` function and next time you go to the `detailviewcontroller` you can register them again.

Answer (score 0):

The comment by lionserdar provided a hint that led to the solution. I was holding a strong reference to detailViewController in my MasterViewController, which created the problem by allowing the object to persist, enabling an extra observer to events from AVPlayer. I made two changes that resolved the problem:

- I eliminated the strong reference to DetailViewController in MasterViewController;
- I overrode the detailViewController's dealloc method, and in that method I removed the previously added observer(s).

Thanks for the help.